# E/SpannableStringBuilder(18909): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length

Tags: android

Getting the above error in log cat, I found quite some hits on this in google but they don't seem to apply to my case.

Currently I have no idea where to start looking or what code/layout to post to get help from you guys.

So where in my code shall I start looking to get rid of this error? The app seems to work as it should, but still I would like to get rid of the error - you never know...

Comment: This doesn't make sense. I get an error and have no idea where to start looking. Not the best situation I know, but it happens. What else I can ask for where to start to look?

Comment: What is the process 18909 ?

Answer (score 3):

Just add this property to your edittext and your problem will definitely be resolved

```
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"
```

Add the above property to each of your edit text used in the application, or simply where you get the error in that edit text only.

Let me know when you are done with it or have some more queries ?
Thanks

Comment: I don't have any EditText in my app.

Comment: has anyone solved this yet? I also don't have any EditText

Comment: @gilsaints88 I have solved it, but only in the case of edittext
Try putting this textNoSuggestion in every view ( input View ) example in the button text iput type.

Comment: @GauravArora I am facing the same problem in webview html input type , how to fix it ? ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23236400/android-keyboard-not-working-in-webview-after-a-validation