# Android keyboard not working in webview after a validation

Tags: javascript, android, input, webview, keyboard

I have an android application , which opens a Jquery mobile site in webview . This page contains almost 20 form fields.**Keyboard works well** , i can able to give input until i type **6 digit number** in a `input[type=number]` box which has a `maxlength=5` attribute. After this keyboard stops working . when i click a element , get focused and keyboard popups but it is not getting the value from keyboard

what might be the problem ? how to get rid of this ?

**Main Activity**

```
        mWebview  = new WebView(this);
        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        mWebview.getSettings().setGeolocationEnabled(true);       
        mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically (true);
        mWebview.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(true);
        mWebview.getSettings().setCacheMode(mWebview.getSettings().LOAD_NO_CACHE);
        mWebview.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
        mWebview.loadUrl(WebUrl);
        setContentView(mWebview);
```

**In Manifest XML**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
```

**HTML in webview**

```
<div class="clsRow">
    <div class='clstdLeft' style='width:50%;'>
        <label>Additional Discount </label>
    </div>
    <div class='clstdRight'>
        <label>
            <input type='number' maxlength=5  value=0>
        </label>
    </div>
</div><div class='clear'>   </div>
```

And log is

```
05-03 12:58:01.593: I/SurfaceTextureClient(5044): [0x53289e48] frames:4, duration:1.222000, fps:3.271073
05-03 12:58:02.570: E/SpannableStringBuilder(5044): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-03 12:58:02.571: E/SpannableStringBuilder(5044): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
05-03 12:58:02.572: V/InputMethodManager(5044): Starting input: view=android.webkit.WebView@41da5668
05-03 12:58:02.572: V/InputMethodManager(5044): Starting input: tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@41ddf148 ic=android.webkit.WebViewClassic$WebViewInputConnection@41e0d6f0
05-03 12:58:02.573: V/InputMethodManager(5044): START INPUT: android.webkit.WebView@41da5668 ic=android.webkit.WebViewClassic$WebViewInputConnection@41e0d6f0 tba=android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo@41ddf148 controlFlags=#0
05-03 12:58:02.574: V/InputMethodManager(5044): Starting input: Bind result=InputBindResult{com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy@41dada48 com.android.inputmethod.latin/.LatinIME #166}
05-03 12:58:02.574: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(5044): endBatchEdit on inactive InputConnection
05-03 12:58:02.710: I/SurfaceTextureClient(5044): [0x53289e48] frames:3, duration:1.111000, fps:2.699259
05-03 12:58:04.126: I/SurfaceTextureClient(5044): [0x53289e48] frames:3, duration:1.421000, fps:2.109934
```

I am **not having this problem** in iball slide (**4.0.3**), I have a problem in HCL me connect-v3 (**4.1.2**) . As it  is a private application for our employees we are going to use this on these tablets

Comment: show your xml and piece of java code

Comment: ohh the same happend to me i used mWebview.setInitialScale(50); thn it worked

Comment: @raj ,Thanks for your suggestion , but it is not working for me

Answer (score 1):

If your layout have TabHost (or similar layout or view), 
TabHost's child may disturb your webview's focus.

I have same problem and I set these view's focusable attr to "false" and works fine.

```
for (int i = 0; i < tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildCount(); i++) {
  tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildAt(i).setFocusable(false);
}
```

Comment: I am a front end developer, I am completely new to native android coding, I too has the same kind of problem in nexus, But not in Moto g, Moto e. As I am using Cordova latest version what should I do @Yuki

Comment: I'm sorry, I've never used Cordova FW, but there must be same API setting focus state.

Answer (score 0):

Try change your `"maxlength=5"` to `onkeypress="if(this.value.length > 4) return false;"`